# Tidak bisa / gagal melakukan upload image dengan database volley android studio

Tags: android-studio

Saya menemukan masalah saat mencoba upload image menggunakan capture image, tidak berjalan dengan baik dan menemukan ke gagalan. tapi setelah saya mencoba menggunakan image yang didapat di gallery tidak menemukan kendala apa pun. tolong bantu saya menemukan masalah saya yang tidak bisa upload image menggunakan capture image. code yang saya dapatkan seperti dibawah ini.

```
appCompatButton=findViewById(R.id.capturImg);
setImgC = findViewById(R.id.imgUpload);
appUploadImg=findViewById(R.id.uploadIMG);
```

**CAPTURE IMAGE**

```
 ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher1 = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if(result.getResultCode()==RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null){
                        Bundle bundle= result.getData().getExtras();
                        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
                        setImgC.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                }
        );
 appCompatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                activityResultLauncher1.launch(intent);
            }
        });
```

**UPLOAD IMAGE**

```
appUploadImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
        byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if(bitmap != null){
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] bytes =byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            final String base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(bytes,Base64.DEFAULT);

            StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, myUrl.ROOT_UPLOAD_IMAGE,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            if(response.equals("success")){
                                Toast.makeText(UploadCamera.this, "Gambar berhasil disimpan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                   Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                   params.put("image",base64Image);
                   return params;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(UploadCamera.this);
            queue.add(req);
        }
    }
});
```